# How is there current if there's no voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

Hi, I was trying to solve this problem, it asks to find the reading of ammeter. I think it has no resistance here. Does it mean that there's no potential difference, no voltage across ammeter? But how is it possible? I thought there would be no current at all then. It is really small, around 0.14 A, but how? PhET sims show the same thing. Current flows with no voltage. Could you help, please?

[image]

Comment: Recommend you read up on Kirchhoff's Laws. Any elementary electrical book or physucs book should cover it well. See openstax.org or  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *real* am-meter (like the one on your desk) has a very small
resistance $R$ (may be $0.001\ \Omega$).
The current ($I$) trough your am-meter and the potential difference
($V$) across it are related by Ohm's law:
$$V=RI$$
That means, for any current $I$ you have a small
potential difference $V$.

---

On the other hand,
an *ideal* am-meter (which, as the name says, is an idealization,
and does not really exist)
has a zero resistance $R=0$. Then Ohm's law from above
becomes $$V=0\cdot I$$
or $$V=0.$$

That means, the current $I$ through the am-meter can be anything,
and the potential difference $V$ across the am-meter is zero.
So there is no contradiction between $V=0$ and $I\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand it now

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we take out the ammeter so the circuit looks like this:

[image: Circuit]

Then the question *what is the reading of ammeter* is simply asking what the value of the current $I_4$ is. Remember that an ideal ammeter does not affect the current flowing in the circuit because it has a zero resistance, so the current $I_4$ will still have the same value before and you insert the ammeter.

So just calculate the value of $I_4$, which you can do using Kirchoff's laws and a lot of patience.

Comment: Thank you, I get the idea now, but how does current I4 flow there, if there's no potential difference? Isn't it still a wire without voltage drop?

Comment: Wires used in circuits have a very small, but non-zero resistance.  The resistance is so small that it's usually ignored, and the wires taken as ideal zero-resistance conductors.